# Bootstrap-vue modal resets window.scrolY on close when shown inside vue-tabulator @row-click event

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-vue, tabulator

I have a **vue-tabulator** table with a `@row-click` event that fires a bootstrap-vue modal, this modal shows perfect when triggered from a button but when fired from the table row, it centers the page vertically, I checked `window.scrolY` property and it's changed. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After A little wait **Rogerio Angeliski** creator of **vue-tabulator** contacted me and came with this neat solution:

`Just put a :return-focus="'body'" in the modal to evict call focus fuction`

And it worked perfect even without the *height* property. I believe this is perfect because I don't want to set a fixed height on the table.

Answer (score 1):

This will be because there is no height or maxHeight set on your table. and will likely be related to a data change rather than the click event itself.

without any height options set on a table it renders using classic mode rather than the virtual DOM. in classic mode the table is redrawn when data is changed which can result in the height of the table momentarily changing, which can result in the scroll position of the browser changing.